# C# lambda simplification

Tags: c#, lambda

I have a class player and player has a list of Shots. Each shot has its own yPos (position) because yPos of the player can change but shot will keep his position:

```
class Player
{
    public string Id { set; get; }
    public int yPos { set; get; }
    public List<Shot> shots;

    public Player(string _Id, int _yPos)
    {
        Id = _Id;
        yPos = _yPos;
    }

}
class Shot
{
    public int yPos { set; get; }
    public Shot(int _yPos)
    {
        yPos = _yPos;
    }
}
```

Then at some point in the game a have id, and I need to find player. and add to list of his shots a new shot with that's players position.
Here is what I ended up with:

```
string tempID = "xxx"; // not important where this temp id is coming from
players.Find(p => p.Id == tempID).shots.Add(new Shot(players.Find(p => p.Id == tempID).yPos));
```

And seems to be fine but looks supper strange. is there a way to simplify this statement so I wouldn't have to look up for the same player twice in one statement?

Comment: I don't understand Lambdas. They seem to sacrifice readability for inefficiency.

Comment: Its ok that you want a shortcut (I do this all the time), but wouldn't it make most sense to add `Player.SetCurrentShotLoc()` method? As Walkerneo pointed out, they are not very readable and you have to know very well when to use them. Use them in appropriate querying situations, not for iterations.

Comment: @Walkerneo Lambda's, when used appropriately, offer readability, performance and functionality.

Comment: I used to not like lambda's a long time ago.  It was because I didn't understand them.  :)  I can't live without them now.......

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would at least cache your player result:

```
var player = players.Find(p => p.Id == tempId);
player.shots.Add(new Shot(player.yPos));
```

Comment: Alternately, add a "AddShot" method to your Player class: AddShot() { this.shots.Add(new Shot(this.ypos)); }

Comment: I just suggested the same thing (re: AddShot). Great minds think alike. :-)

Comment: I'll take those complements from people w/ more rep than me :D

Answer (score 4):

Instead of reaching into the Player to pull out its yPos value and creating a new Shot with it, and then shoving that Shot into the Player's Shot collection (how rude!), you could simplify things a bit by giving your Player a bit more smarts:

```
class Player
{
    public string Id { set; get; }
    public int yPos { set; get; }
    public List<Shot> shots;

    public Player(string _Id, int _yPos)
    {
        Id = _Id;
        yPos = _yPos;
    }

    public void AddShotToYPos()
    {
        shots.Add(new Shot(yPos));
    }
}
```

Then you could say:

```
players.Find(p => p.Id == tempID).AddShotToYPos();
```

Comment: +1 I much prefer this method, or if you don't want the behavior in the Player class, an extension method.

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of possibly stating something obvious, this would do one less lookup, and is possibly more readable:

```
string tempID = "xxx";
var player = players.Find(p => p.Id == tempID);
player.shots.Add(new Shot(player.yPos));
```

Answer (score 0):

KISS:

```
var p = players.Find(p => p.Id == tempID);
p.shots.Add(new Shot(p.yPos));
```

Pointlessly long LINQ:

```
(from p in players
         where p.Id == tempID
         select p).Take(1).ToList().ForEach(p => p.shots.Add(new Shot(p.yPos)));
```

Nice and Short Extension:

```
players.Find(p => p.Id == tempID).Shoot();
...
static class Extensions
{
    public static void Shoot(this Player p)
    {
        p.shots.Add(new Shot(p.yPos));
    }
}
```

Cooler Lambda

```
(from p in players
         where p.Id == tempID
         let x = new Func<bool>(() => { p.shots.Add(new Shot(p.yPos)); return true; })
         select x()).First();
```

Comment: I wouldn't consider caching KISS, but your code is an improvement.

Comment: @Guvante  Given my alternatives [now added] - especially the LINQ solution - I think it is KISS :P